# Changing the background color of a disabled input field

Tags: css

I am trying to find a way to disable the background color of a disabled input field. I was wondering if someone can help me with this?

This is what I tried, which did not work:

```
 input[type="text"][disabled]{background-color:red;}
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I am not trying to change the text-color, instead I am trying to change the background color. Read the question before down voting.

Comment: My mistake, I misread - DV changed to UV. Downvoting a question + response of mine in retaliation however is not a suitable response.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
input[type="text"]:disabled{background-color:red;}
```

Source: [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp)

Comment: Better sources: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) and [CSS2 Selector Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). Also, please read this [w3schools discussion](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to catch all input types

```
input:disabled {
   background-color: red;
}
```